# Timed Script Function

Tags: sql-server

I want to run a daily script file on a Windows based SQL server.  Currently I'm running it on a Linux machine so all I have to type is: "./MyScript.sh" and it runs once.

I'm not familiar with SQL Servers, not really sure if they have a terminal similar to Linux.  Does anyone know how I would get this script to run everyday at 7:30am on a 2008 SQL server? Could I just enter a command into a terminal of sorts and still use the terminal for other tasks? I believe I don't have access to Crontab.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Sql Server Agent is your friend, have a look here [`SQL Server Agent`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For a terminal of sorts you could use cmd.exe (Start / Run / cmd.exe) and then use [sqlcmd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165702%28v=sql.105%29.aspx);  sqlcmd /? will show the many options. You could then create a batch file that could be scheduled with the [Windows Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Or as M.Ali says, if you are running an edition and version of SQL that has the SQL Server Agent, add jobs using Sql Server Management Studio.